# About the tangent space of a coadjoint orbit

Tags: lie-groups, smooth-manifolds, quotient-spaces, symplectic-geometry

Let $G$ be a Lie group, $\mathfrak g$ its Lie algebra and consider the coadjoint action:
$$\begin{array}{rcll}
&G\times \mathfrak g^\star&\longrightarrow &\mathfrak g^\star\\
&(g,\xi)&\longmapsto & Ad_g^\star(\xi)
\end{array}$$
If $\mathcal O^\star$ is a coadjoint orbit, then:
$$\begin{array}{rcll}
&G\times \mathcal O^\star&\longrightarrow &\mathcal O^\star\\
&(g,\xi)&\longmapsto & Ad_g^\star(\xi)
\end{array}$$
must be a transitive action. Therefore the quotient manifold $G/G_\xi$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathcal O^\star$ via:
$$g\cdot G_\xi\longmapsto Ad_g^\star(\xi)$$
where $G_\xi$ is the isotropy group of $\xi\in\mathfrak g$.

**My question is:**

From here, how can we get an isomorphism between $\mathfrak g/\mathfrak g_\xi$ and the tangent space $T_\xi\mathcal O^\star$? ($\mathfrak g_\xi$ is the Lie algebra of $G_\xi$). Maybe taking the induced map?

Many thank!

Comment: Yes, the isomorphism is the differential of the map $G/G_{\xi} \to \mathcal O^*$.